# What free tools are available to analyze lock contention in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I need to determine which locks are the most-contended-for in my application code. What free tools can I use to determine this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use jconsole or jstack both in the bin directory of your JDK.  The jconsole in particular allows you to connect to your process and monitor the threads including which resources they have locked, and it can help you identify a deadlock state.

Comment: I think the question relates to some statistics about the lock contention during the application run - which are the hot locks in the system.

Answer (score 3):

You can also view this in eclipse's debugger. In the Debug view, use the little down-triangle menu on the view toolbar to turn on "Java->Show Monitors".

When you suspect a deadlock, pause the application (select the application in the debug view and press the pause button on the debug view toolbar) and if there's a deadlock, the blocking threads will turn red. If you expand those threads you can see the lock contention.

Answer (score 2):

VisualVM (Part of Java 1.6) ([see](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/))

Comment: Doesn't VisualVM require a separate plugin for that?

Answer (score 2):

The JDK has some built-in support - under unix, kill -3 the process, under windows, ctrl-break.  This will display a complete thread dump, followed by any deadlocks detected.  Plus, in the thread dusmp you can see what threads own what locks, and compare them to each other.

Comment: You don't need to kill the process in order to get a thread dump - just run jstack <pid> where <pid> is the process id.

Comment: The kill -3 command doesn't kill the process.  It just signals it, but the process will continue to run.

Answer (score 2):

If you own the code, you could create/look for a Lock implementation which gathers contention statistics. If not, try the tools suggested in the other posts.

Comment: do you have any examples of this sort of implementation (ie java code)